# How to write a single function without explicitly using their classes/ Id in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html like the below,

```
<input class="btn btn-primary button1" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button2" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button3" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button4" type="button" value="0">
```

There can be `any number of buttons in the HTML`.

But, though the number of `buttons`in the HTML increases, I cannot write everytime in the JS like the below,

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
  buttonVal(this);
});

$(".button2").click(function() {
  buttonVal(this);
});
$(".button3").click(function() {
  buttonVal(this);
});
...... for button 4 and so on....
```

```
//Single function
function buttonVal(ele)
{
  var v = +$(ele).attr('value');
  $(ele).attr('value', v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
  
}
```

Each buttons Value will be `0` initially.

When each button is clicked the values will be increased by 1 and When the value reaches `3`, again cliking the button after `3`. The Value should become `0`.

The same condition applies for all the newly added buttons.

I need a `single function`, that supports any number of buttons when added, instead of adding each button to the click event in the JS and not by calling their `classes` explicitly.

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

loop over the buttons and add the event listener for each one

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
btns.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventLisetner("click", () => {
    buttonVal(x);
  })
})
```

this is pure js, so no need for jquery  here

Answer (score 2):

Just try like this

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele)
{
  var v = +$(ele).attr('value');
  $(ele).attr('value', v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary button1" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button2" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button3" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button4" type="button" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="btn btn-primary button" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button" type="button" value="0">
<input class="btn btn-primary button" type="button" value="0">

$(".button").click(function() {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele)
{
  var v = +$(ele).attr('value');
  $(ele).attr('value', v > 2 ? 0 : v + 1);
  
}
```

U work in good condition, but you overwrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with querySelectorAll and a foreach loop.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    button.value >= 3 ? button.value = 0 : button.value++;
  })
});
```

```html
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="0">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="0">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="0">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="0">
```